# Pyqt - QMenu dynamically populated and clicked

Tags: python, user-interface, qt, pyqt

I need to be able to know what item I've clicked in a dynamically generated menu system. I only want to know what I've clicked on, even if it's simply a string representation.

```
def populateShotInfoMenus(self):
    self.menuFilms = QMenu()
    films = self.getList()

    for film in films:
        menuItem_Film = self.menuFilms.addAction(film)
        self.connect(menuItem_Film, SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.onFilmSet)
        self.menuFilms.addAction(menuItem_Film)

def onFilmRightClick(self, value):
    self.menuFilms.exec_(self.group1_inputFilm.mapToGlobal(value))

def onFilmSet(self, value):
    print 'Menu Clicked ', value
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `onFilmSet` directly as the receiver of your connection, use a lambda function so you can pass additional parameters:

```
receiver = lambda film=film: self.onFilmSet(self, film)
self.connect(menuItem_Film, SIGNAL('triggered()'), receiver)
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, ahhh sweet lambda!

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319889/pyqt5-whats-this-boolean-passed-when-a-menu-action-is-triggered) answer here for dealing with this issue in PyQt5, python3. I don't like it, the bVal variable to be precise, as I don't fully understand it but it took a long time to find so I thought I'd share it here. The bVal picks up the boolean value from triggered and allows the taskType to be passed.

```
self.taskMenu = QtGui.QMenu("Task")
self.tasks = self.getTasks() #FETCHES A LIST OF LIST
self.menuTasks = QtGui.QMenu()

for item in self.tasks:
   menuItem_Task = self.taskMenu.addAction(item[1]) 
   receiver = lambda: bVal, taskType=item: self.setTask(bVal, taskType)
   menuItem_Task.triggered.connect(receiver)
   self.taskMenu.addAction(menuItem_Task)

def setTask(self, ignore_bVal, taskType):
   print taskType
```

Comment: You don't need to pass `bVal` to `setTask`, so you can get rid of that ugly `ignore_bVal`. The only requirement is that you insert an initial argument in the `lambda` so that the `taskType` argument doesn't get overwritten with the boolean value. A slightly more robust (and more general) solution would be to replace `bVal` with `*args` - which would then ignore *all possible* values sent by the signal, and leave the keyword arguments untouched.

Comment: I was able to solve a similar problem with Python3 and PyQt5 thanks to this answer. This idea applied can also be seen here: https://github.com/muammar/mkchromecast/commit/719fde94e271f97a2047e84b56d7603a5d8cde09

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Qt's property system. You can dynamically add a property containing a string or anything you desire, which defines the action. Then you can use sender() method in the slot to obtain the QObject calling the slot. Then, query the property you set and do whatever you want accordingly.

But, this is not the best method to do this. Using sender() is not advised because it violates the object oriented principle of modularity.

The best method would be using QSignalMapper class. This class maps signals from different objects to the same slot with different arguments.

I haven't used PyQt therefore i cannot give you exact syntax or an example, but it shouldn't be hard to find with a little research.

Comment: I agree that this seems like the place to use a signal mapper.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure out a similar issue and after looking at the code above this is what worked for me.  Thought it would be good to show it all together. =)

```
self.taskMenu = QtGui.QMenu("Task")
self.tasks = self.getTasks() #FETCHES A LIST OF LIST
self.menuTasks = QtGui.QMenu()
for item in self.tasks:
     menuItem_Task = self.taskMenu.addAction(item[1]) 
     receiver = lambda taskType=item[0]: self.setTask(taskType)
     self.connect(menuItem_Task, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), receiver)
     self.taskMenu.addAction(menuItem_Task)

def setTask(self,taskType):
     print taskType
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some additional information,
I don't know why, but lambda function doesn't work with new pyqt syntax for connections :

Example of code not working :

```
    self.contextTreeMenuAssignTo = QtGui.QMenu(self)
    actionAssign = contextMenu.addMenu( self.contextTreeMenuAssignTo )
    actionAssign.setText("Assign to : ")
    for user in self.whoCanBeAssignated() :
        actionAssignTo = QtGui.QAction( user[0]  ,self)
        self.contextTreeMenuAssignTo.addAction( actionAssignTo )
        actionAssignTo.triggered.connect(  lambda userID = user[1] :  self.assignAllTo( userID )  )
```

But if you subsitute the last line with the old style connection syntax :

```
self.connect(actionAssignTo, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'),  lambda userID = user[1] :  self.assignAllTo( userID )  )
```

Everything is fine. 
With the new connection syntax, you only get the last element of the loop :(

Comment: For me (Qt4) it also works with the new connection syntax, see my comment to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1102089/3224008