# PyQT5: What's this boolean passed when a menu action is triggered?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

So I'm relatively new at Python, and I've been trying to learn PyQt. I wanted to create a menu dynamically based on the contents of a list. I found an example which I adapted and it looked like this:

```
  for someText in myList:
        entry = QAction(someText,MainWindow)
        self.myMenu.addAction(entry)
        entry.triggered.connect(lambda menuItem=someText: self.doStuff(menuItem))
        entry.setText(someText)
```

The menu was created but when a menu item was chosen doStuff() always got passed a value of False. So I changed the above to:

```
  for someText in myList:
        entry = QAction(someText,MainWindow)
        self.myMenu.addAction(entry)
        entry.triggered.connect(lambda bVal, menuItem=someText: self.doStuff(bVal,menuItem))
        entry.setText(someText)
```

and sure enough everything now works as I'd like. I still get the False in bVal which I just ignore.

I've tried looking at the PyQt documentation but the reference section links to the C++ documentation and it's not obvious to me from that what's going on.

I'd like to understand what the boolean value is and why, in my case, it's always False. I've tried changing various things but I haven't managed to find a scenario where it's True.

Thanks

PyQT5.4, Python 3.4.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ documentation for the [triggered signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered) shouldn't be too hard to understand:

> void QAction::​triggered(bool checked = false)
>   ...
>   If the action is checkable, checked is true if the action is checked, or false if the action is unchecked.

So the signal is emitted with a boolean parameter which indicates the action's 'checked' state, and this parameter overwrote the default value for your `menuItem` argument.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I couldn't find that.

Comment: In PyQt/PySide, you must explictly ask for the checked state, otherwise it will always send `False` (even if the action is has been set checkable). So you would need to do `action.triggered[bool].connect(...)`.