# PyQt QObject.connect(instancemethod) and QtCore.connect(Qobj, SIGNAL(), instancemethod) behave differently to lambda function

Tags: lambda, pyqt, signals, connect, slot

In follow up to [Create PyQt menu from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100775/create-pyqt-menu-from-a-list-of-strings) i'm also creating menu's on the fly and want to know which menu item was clicked. Therefore I used a piece of code like:

```
for item in ADDABLE_OBJECTS:
     action = self.menuAdd.addAction(item)
     l = lambda item=item: self.doStuff(item)
     action.triggered.connect(l)

def doStuff(self, item):
  print "Item: ", item
```

Ouput:

> Item: False    (default 'bool' param as stated in Qt Docs for triggered() signal)

As I thought that object.connect() is the 'new' form as compared to connect(object, SIGNAL(...), slot). I also works better as the signal names can be checked at compile time.
However, it did not work. All I got passed was the 'bool=false' (as stated in the Qt docs for triggered()). So after searching came across the above mention url. No I have this:

```
for item in ['One', 'Two', 'Three']:
    action = self.menuAdd.addAction(item)
    l = lambda item=item: self.doStuff(item)
    action.triggered.connect(l)
    self.connect(action, SIGNAL('triggered()'), l)
```

Which gives (on clicking the menu once):

> Item: False (the action.triggered.connect(l) line, wrong)
>   Item: One (the self.connect line, right)

Why do these two behave different? I have never noticed any difference between the two kinds of connect before, not until I used this lambda construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about the `lambda`, but rather how the signals with default arguments are implemented in Qt.

```
void triggered(bool = 0)
```

is actually two signals:

```
void triggered(bool)
void triggered()
```

[PyQt docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qaction.html#triggered) mention the default overload for this signal as `triggered(bool)` and since your function accepts an argument it can successfully connect this signal to your function. Therefore the `bool` parameter is passed for the `item`.

[You can choose specific overloads by indexing syntax](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals). In this case you want the signal with no parameters, so you would do:

```
action.triggered[()].connect(l)
```

Comment: I get it, the second method actually binds to the no-parameter slot. Thanx!